# sum of square roots upper bound

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, geometric-series

> I want to know whether there exists a constant $c$ such that for any $k$ the following inequality holds:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sqrt{2^i} \leq c \sqrt{2^k}$$

This is not a homework. Could somebody provide me with a proof or at least a pointer on how to solve this?

Comment: I didn't understand that. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Take the power in lhs to be i/2.The common ratio would be $2pow((i+1)/2-i/2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \sqrt{2^i}
 = \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\sqrt2\right)^i
 = \frac{\left(\sqrt2\right)^{k+1} - 1}{\sqrt2 - 1}
 \le \left(\sqrt2\right)^k \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2 - 1}
$$

So let $c$ be any number at least $\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2-1} \le 3.415$

Comment: thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the sum into an integral by considering it a Riemann sum of the function $2^{x/2}$.  You can bound the sum between the integral from $0$ to $k$ and the integral from $1$ to $k+1$